# How do I reset USB devices using the Windows API?

Tags: winapi, usb

Do you know a way to use the Windows XP API to reset the USB bus? In other words, I'd like the OS to kick out any USB devices that are currently connected, and then auto-detect everything anew.

I'm aware of [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272), and I suppose I could do system calls out to it, but I'm hoping for a direct call into the API.

Answer (score 13):

**From kernel mode:** You can force a specific USB device to be re-connected, as if it was unplugged and replugged again, by sending an `IOCTL_INTERNAL_USB_CYCLE_PORT` to its PDO. (This can only be done from a kernel mode, e.g. through a helper driver.) This 'cycle' operation will cause a USB reset to occur, after which the device would be re-enumerated. For example, if the device comes back with a different USB device descriptor, a different driver may be matched for it.

**From user mode:** You can do this by ejecting the device through the CfgMgr API. For example, to go over all USB hubs and eject all devices:

1. Find all devices having device interface `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB` with `SetupDiGetClassDevs(... DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE)`.
2. Enumerate over the returned device information set (`SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`).
3. For each device, get the `DevInst` member:

   1. Invoke `CM_Get_Child(DevInst)` and then `CM_Get_Sibling` repeatedly to go over all child nodes of the hub (i.e. the USB devices).
   2. For each child node, call `CM_Request_Device_Eject`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, use can use the Setup API (SetupDiXXX functions) to enumerate the USB devices in the system, and then call WinUsb_ResetPipe on each one, but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.  It's been a while since I worked with USB devices, but as I recall, there is no standard way to reset a device (i.e. simulate a power off/power on cycle).  If it's possible for a particular device, you'd have to send an appropriate IOCTL (using DeviceIOControl) to the driver.  The IOCTL would vary from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to cycle the parent port on the USB hub the device is attached to, as well.  This will result in, among other things, apparrent unplug/replug actions, as you will see a balloon popup when this occurs.

Much of this is poorly documented, and honestly, I've gotten the impression there are only a handful of people at Microsoft who really understand it well.  The design decision I've made for future devices I design is that I intend to include watchdog functionality on both sides, as well as a device-side full reset function.  That way, if the device figures out it is confused, it can just cut its own power for a second and fully reset, if the host can't communicate with it, it could do the same thing, and if the device thinks everything is fine but the host knows better, the host could order it to reset.

There are at least three APIs worth looking into for this problem: the Setup API, the Config Manager API, and various WMI extensions.  However, be cautious about diving into WMI if you intend to use an Embedded XP target, as you will have to include a lot of other things in your OS image you might otherwise not need.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this - you can issue a command to have PnP *rescan* the bus for new devices, but that isn't the same as issuing a bus reset.

Furthermore, just because from a hardware perspective you issued a bus reset doesn't mean that Windows will remove the PDOs that represent the children of the hub and redetect them; the USB bus driver can (and does) do just what I describe (i.e. issue hardware bus resets without disturbing the device tree), and only *after* the device doesn't respond does it issue the surprise removal and yank it from the tree.