# Which library GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB is defined

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2015, usb

This question relates to: [**How do I reset USB devices using the Windows API?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987958/how-do-i-reset-usb-devices-using-the-windows-api#)  I am using Vistual Studio 2015 and the project target platform is `Win10.0.14393.0`.

I am trying to use the user space solution to to make the USB HUB device interface re-enumerate by calling to `CM_Reenumerate_DevInst()`.

The problem that I have is when calling
`SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);`

I get this compilation error.

```
1>UsbDevices.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB
1>C:\DEV\Experiment\MFCApplication1\x64\Debug\MFCApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I cannot find the library where this GUID is defined.

Comment: however instead `SetupDiGetClassDevs` I advice use `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` with `&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB` after this `CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW` for `&DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId` on every interface. than `CM_Locate_DevNodeW` and finally `CM_Request_Device_Eject`

Comment: I would like to thank you @RbMm. I could not get it working without your suggestion. I have a question though. Part of my testing, I would need to issue `IOCTR` command. Like your recommendation, Is there a property to retrieve the device path? So I can create a file (`CreateFile2 ()`) and do an IO control (`DeviceIoControl()`).

Comment: `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`( with `&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB`) and return you name, which you can use in call `CreateFile`. interface name - this is symbolic link to device

Comment: if you want get exactly *PDO* device name, you can use `CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW` for `&DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId` on interface. than `CM_Locate_DevNodeW` and `CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW` with `DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName` - however this will be only another name of the same device

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this not implemented in any library. all what you need:

```
#include <initguid.h>
#include <usbiodef.h>
```

so include *`initguid.h`* **before** *`usbiodef.h`*

the `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB` variable defined with `DEFINE_GUID` macro. this macro defined in *`guiddef.h`* in different way - depending on are `INITGUID` is defined. finally look for *`initguid.h`* - what this tiny file do.

Comment: But note that **only one** compilation unit in each project should `#include <initguid,h>`

Comment: @BenVoigt - this is depend from compiler. the guid declared with `DECLSPEC_SELECTANY`. which in case `_MSC_VER >= 1100` expanded to `__declspec(selectany)` - as result we can have this in multiple compilation units. so if we use `CL.exe` this is not a problem. if we use another compiler - yes, you right - we need include `usbiodef.h` in every place where we use `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_HUB` and only in one selected place include `initguid.h` before `usbiodef.h`